# CakePHP AssetCompress plugin and fonts

Tags: cakephp, plugins, fonts, assets

I have a custom font imported into CSS with `@font-face`, which worked fine. When trying to use Mark Story's [`AssetCompress`](https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress) plugin, I included the CSS file in the `.ini` file. While the font works (for now, but it may be cached), I get an error.

Snippet of CSS file (the `font` directory is in the `css` directory):

```
...
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ArvoRegular';
    src: url('font/arvo-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/arvo-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/arvo-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/arvo-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/arvo-regular-webfont.svg#ArvoRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
...
```

Console error (Chrome):

```
GET http://localhost/.../cache_css/font/arvo-bold-webfont.woff 404 (Not Found)
```

Why is this error occurring and how to I get rid of it? Also, I get a CakePHP `NotFoundException` when visiting that URL in the browser, which is why I think the font is working from cache now.

### Edit

The full (real) path is: `http://localhost/_active/website-under-development/css/font/arvo-regular-webfont.eot` and the homepage is at `http://localhost/_active/website-under-development/`

The directory structure for the webroot is:

```
/webroot/
   |--css/
   |----font/
   |------arvo-regular-webfont.eot
   |------other font files...
   |----main.css
   |----other CSS files...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Make urls relative to the webroot

The [default configuration](https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress/wiki#defining-an-ini-file) for the asset compress plugin has the cache folders at the same level as the source folders:

```
[General]
cacheConfig = false

[js]
cachePath = WEBROOT/cache_js/

[css]
cachePath = WEBROOT/cache_css/
```

Therefore the folder structure is as follows:

```
app
    webroot
        cache_css
        cache_js
        css
        js
        img
```

Instead of defining urls relative to the location of the file - define them relative to the webroot:

```
/* /css/some.css */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ArvoRegular';
    src: url('../css/font/arvo-regular-webfont.eot');

/* /css/some/other.css */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ArvoRegular';
    src: url('../../css/font/arvo-regular-webfont.eot');
```

This permits font files/images in css files to be found however they are accessed. I.e. All of the following css files would find the right font files:

```
http://localhost/myproject/css/some.css
http://localhost/myproject/css_cache/123123.css
http://localhost/myclient/myproject/css/some.css
http://localhost/myclient/myproject/css_cache/123123.css
http://myproject.dev/css/some.css
http://myproject.dev/css_cache/123123.css
http://cdn.myproject.com/version123/css_cache/123123.css
```

Comment: Then the font files are not where you say they are. What url _does_ reach the font files?

Comment: There are two levels of directories, and the full path is: ```http://localhost/_active/websites-under-development/css/font/arvo-regular-webfont.eot```

The directory structure for the webroot is:

    /webroot/
       |--css/
       |----font/
       |------arvo-regular-webfont.eot
       |----styles.css

Comment: From the updated question the font files are located `../css/font` from your css files - whether they are compressed or not. If the font files exist (does the css folder not exist when the compressed css files are in use?) yet are not found with the use of relative urls for the font files, just compare the http request for the font files with the url that does work and identify in what way they are different - and then correct your css file appropriately.

Comment: The regular URL of ```http://localhost/_active/websites-under-development/css/font/arvo-regular-webfo‌​nt.eot``` works fine. The issue is, when using AssetCompress with this CSS file, and the new combined CSS file is ```http://localhost/_active/websites-under-development/cache_css/font/combined-css.css```, it's looking for the font file at ```http://localhost/_active/websites-under-development/cache_css/font/arvo-regular-webfo‌​nt.eot```, and for some reason it's not coming up and CakePHP shows an error.

Comment: You are under the impression that asset compress is going to _make_ the url `cache_css/font/arvo-regular‌​-webfo‌​nt.eot` work; That's not the case. Asset compress will only create css (and js) files, the (absolute) url to reach the font files won't change when comparing the compressed and uncompressed css file. Or: It isn't working because you are still requesting a url for a file that doesn't exist - it needs to reach `.../css/font/arvo-regular‌​-webfo‌​nt.eot`. You can use either answer to achieve that (though only this answer will work irrespective of the document root), good luck :).

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with relativly linked assets. If its images or fonts.
The paths wont match after compressing and storing those files in a different location ("cache_css" folder in your case).

So **always** link your assets relative to root (not the current file) to avoid this.
From root (for `http://www.domain.de/` it's `/` - the part after the domain) it will always be accessible with the same url, thus always be reachable, no matter where the final compressed css will be located at.

```
// if the file is in WEBROOT/css/font/
url('/css/font/arvo-regular-webfont.svg#ArvoRegular')
```

PS: and try to avoid those localhost setups. use vhosts and a local url like "my.website.local" etc.

Comment: What exactly did you do? You need to be more specific. I bet you still didnt root it to your root properly (note that for localhost the root consists of all folders to your app - and why you shouldnt use localhost as setup if possible). Also make sure you refresh your css/js (clear cache) to avoid that the old files are still in use.

Comment: I used absolute paths is my CSS file to load the font files, and still get the same error. Likewise, the font file(s) is/are not accessible via .../cache_css/font/...
Yes, I know I should use vhosts, but can't set that up right now.